# package doesn't exist, <identifier> expected

Tags: java

I have a class:

```
public class TypeOfCompressDTO {

    private int typeOfCompressId;
    private String typeOfCompress;

    public TypeOfCompressDTO() {
    }

    public TypeOfCompressDTO(int typeOfCompressId, String typeOfCompress) {
        this.typeOfCompressId = typeOfCompressId;
        this.typeOfCompress = typeOfCompress;
    }

    public int getTypeOfCompressId() {
        return typeOfCompressId;
    }

    public void setTypeOfCompressId(int typeOfCompressId) {
        this.typeOfCompressId = typeOfCompressId;
    }

    public String getTypeOfCompress() {
        return typeOfCompress;
    }

    public void setTypeOfCompress(String typeOfCompress) {
        this.typeOfCompress = typeOfCompress;
    }

}
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FmCompressComposer  extends BaseCustomComposer<FmCompressService, FmCompressDTO>{

    Window wdwFmCompress;

    //public ListModelList<TypeOfCompressDTO> listTypeOfProcess = new ListModelList();
    List<TypeOfCompressDTO> lstTypeOfCompress = new ArrayList<TypeOfCompressDTO>();
    TypeOfCompressDTO assssa = new TypeOfCompressDTO(3, "abc");
    lstTypeOfCompress.add(assssa);
    TypeOfCompressDTO g = new TypeOfCompressDTO(23, "axbc");  

//    public ListModel<TypeOfCompress> getListTypeOfProcess() {
//        return listTypeOfProcess;
//    }

    @Override
    protected Logger getLogger() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    protected Window getWindow() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    protected Listbox getGridData() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getArgDTOKey() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void buildSearchObject() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

At this line:

```
lstTypeOfCompress.add(assssa);
```

In class `FmCompressComposer`, Netbeans 7.x notice that:

> package lstTypeOfCompress does not exist 
>   expected
>
> expected
>
> (Alt-Enter shows hints)

I don't understand what happen, it looks so strange. Please explain and help me correct the above snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lstTypeOfCompress.add(assssa);
```

This is a statement/expression. It should inside a be method/constructor. You can only declare members and initialize them. But you are performing operation, which is not allowed.

By looking at your code, I think you should define a constructor for initialization the members of the class and their you can add the data also in the list.

Comment: It is a compilation issue, not sure why he's getting package doesn't exist, expected

Comment: @Ankushsoni I am guessing this message is generated from the Netbean IDE, which is considering it as package, and method call `add` as class. then it becomes constructor call. PS: I don't use Netbeans, this is my speculation.